# c++ overflow while calculating an arithmetic expression

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << 30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207) / 2 + 50488389 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The right answer I want is 1967383389, but this program outputted -180100259 after running on my computer. It seemed it had overflowed. But why? How can I judge whether an ***arithmetic expression*** will overflow?

Comment: I would think that if you used compile time constants as shown in the question, you'd get a compile time warning.

Comment: Yes, the compiler did give me a warning, but I didn't mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile your example code, the compiler usually throws a warning identifying exactly the part of your expression that overflows

```
main.cpp:4:24: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     std::cout << 30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207) / 2 + 50488389 << std::endl;
                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4629351ce1017f34)

---

To overcome this, use all floating point constants to do this calculation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << std::trunc(30000.0 * (5.0 * 30000.0 - 22207.0) / 2.0 + 50488389.0) << std::endl;
                              // ^^     ^^        ^^        ^^     ^^           ^^

    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09cf372b57095bc6)

---

> How can I judge whether an arithmetic expression will overflow?

You can check the [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to see what are the maximum values, that are available with your compiler implementation and target CPU.

---

If you need the exact output as it was mentioned in your question, you can use I/O manipulators to bang the output in shape:

```
std::cout  << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) 
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           << std::trunc(30000.0 * (5.0 * 30000.0 - 22207.0) / 2.0 + 50488389.0) << std::endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/792c14ae7ca6100c)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! Anyway, I can solve the current question now. But I still want to know why a compiler cannot just detect the size of a variable(or the value of an expression) and allocate enough space to store it?

Comment: _"... and allocate enough space to store it?"_ The primitive types and their actual sizes introduced by implementation and CPU target are fixed already, there's not much room for a compiler to apply automatic allocation.

Comment: Your `trunc` is in the wrong place, it needs to surround the divide itself. In this case it doesn't matter, because `30000 * x` will always divide evenly by 2, but in other contexts it could make a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question, overflow is controlled by size of the type.  The common C++ types are int (32-bit), long (64-bit), float(32-bit) and double (64-bit).  Depending on the platform the size of the types may vary so caution must be observed when dealing with large numbers.  An int type of 64-bit is common these days for example but may be 16-bit on some old embedded platforms.

In your case, an intermediate value exceeded the sizeof(int) which appears to be 32 bit.  The result will be rubbish.   You can use floating point as the other suggested, that can lead to round of error in certain cases however.

If you stick with integer literals, can you can assign the type with a trailing letter. There are a lot of details here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

I prefer to use variable of the explicit size that I'm interested in int32_t or int64_t for example.

Hope that help,

--Matt

Comment: A `double` (IEEE) can hold any integer of 53 bits or less without rounding.

Comment: I didn't know that exact number, 53.  Thanks

Comment: It comes from the way floating point numbers are stored. [IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_numbers) contains 52 bits of fraction in a double, and there's an implied 1-bit on the left side that doesn't need to be stored, for a total of 53.

Answer (score 0):

It has overflowed because **30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207)** evaluates to 3833790000 which is greater than the largest integer an int can hold. Constants in an arithmetic expression are treated as int type and an arithmetic operation on two int types will result in int type only, so overflow occurred.

You can check whether an arithmetic expression containing constants will overflow by compiling the above code with g++ in unix/linux. It will throw a warning when compiling like this -

**warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]**

To get the desired answer you can just convert the type of any constant in **30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207)** to type long like **long(30000) * (5 * 30000 - 22207)**

Comment: What the limits actually are varies with compiler implementations and target CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the overflow is the following:

```
30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207) / 2 + 50488389
```

is calculated from left to right. The result of calculating

```
30000 * (5 * 30000 - 22207)
```

is

```
3833790000
```

which is equivalent to

```
-461177296
```

modulo 2^32. Here the overflow occurs, because you use a 32-bit signed integer datatype.

Calculating

```
-461177296 / 2 + 50488389
```

then gives you

```
-180100259
```

To my knowledge, you cannot directly detect if an overflow had occurred. A possible way is to insert some assembly code into your C++ code and check the overflow flag. (But you have to have a good understanding of compilers and your system in order to get it working correctly.)